# Why won't Xamarin Forms Webview binding refresh on iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using the WebView and building my own html. I want to bind the webview to changes elsewhere on the form. Here is my xaml:

```
        <WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 Margin="0">
            <WebView.Source>
                <HtmlWebViewSource x:Name="WebViewSoruce1" Html="{Binding Description}"/>
            </WebView.Source>
        </WebView>
```

Here is my model code for the Description:

```
    public string Description
    {
        get {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

This works fine on Android but not for iOS. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if anyone else runs into this problem. This is what finally worked for me on both iOS and Android.

I had to bind as a WebViewSource to its Source attribute and not to the HTML. Here is my XAML:

```
<WebView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 Margin="0"  Source="{Binding WebViewSource}"/>
```

In my view model I have two properites. One to bind the HTML changes, I named it as Description. The other was to bind to the WebViewSource.

Here is the code-behind:

```
    public HtmlWebViewSource WebViewSource
    {
        get
        {
            return new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = _description };
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get {
            return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            RaisePropertyChanged("WebViewSource");
        }
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: That works. Thanks... I think it's a bug https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2952